# Why can't I compare to '_' char in an "if" statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, char

Trying to search a `StringBuffer` for appearances of the `_` character. My code is below but when I run I get `Match` printing for every digit in the `StringBuffer`.

Don't know if it makes a difference but am running this code on a learning website and so don't have a pure Java debugger. I have checked the standard escape characters and this isn't one of them so am out of ideas.

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(functionName);
System.out.println(buffer);
char compare='_';
char x;
for(int i=0;i<buffer.length();i++){
  x = buffer.charAt(i);
  System.out.println(x);
  if(x==compare);
  System.out.println("Match");
}
```

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: use `equals` method not `==`

Comment: @kaanyılmaz **wrong**. for comparing `char`, `==` is the **proper** way to go, as with all the primitives.

Comment: also, FWIW, *any* decent IDE would issue a warning on that particular line, saying exactly what's wrong with it. It's OP's fault he's not using one in this case. Also, using Always Put Braces Around rule/reformatting can be helpful here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can if you remove `;` after the condition

```
if (x == compare) {
    System.out.println("Match");
}
```

For your case, it looks like

```
if (x == compare); // if `x` and `compare` are equal, we do nothing
System.out.println("Match"); // it prints out `Match` regardless of the condition
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the one! Sneaky Semi-colon...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is on this line:

```
if(x==compare);
```

You end the if sentence here, due to the `;`. So, it will print `"Match"` every time.

Remove the `;` and make it:

```
if(x==compare)
```

Then it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

```
StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer(functionName);
System.out.println(buffer);
char compare='_';
char x;
for(int i=0;i<buffer.length();i++){
  x = buffer.charAt(i);
  System.out.println(x);
  if(x==compare) System.out.println("Match");
}
```

With `;` you end the statement, so it will do nothing in `if`, and will continue to next line, which is printing. You need to move printing inside if, and since its the only statement there, you dont need `{}`.

**Problem you had is the reason why you should use braces even if you don't need them.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer(functionName);
System.out.println(buffer);
char compare='_';
char x;
for(int i=0;i<buffer.length();i++){
  x = buffer.charAt(i);
  System.out.println(x);
  if(x==compare)
  System.out.println("Match");
}
```

If you add ';' after if statement next instruction isn't consider to be into the if condition!

Answer (score 1):

It happens sometime we forget to remove semicolon from if statement, So it's  better to use conditional operator over here. Below is the source code.

```
StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer(functionName);
System.out.println(buffer);
char compare='_';
char x;
for(int i=0;i<buffer.length();i++){
    x = buffer.charAt(i);
    System.out.println((x==compare)?x+" Match":x);
}
```